# using CodeFirst DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using Code First entity framework. But i have a problem. Ex. I have a table, there are over 10000 lines. in this case i want to add a new field, or even a table, or new foreign key. But I get the error in this case.

> The model backing the 'Context' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database

My context like this:

```
static Context()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context>());
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does your project has EF Migrations configured? I.e. do you have a class that implements `DbMigrationsConfiguration`?

Comment: i dont have like class "DbMigrationsConfiguration"
How should I do?

Comment: Assuming you use EF6, your project has a folder called `Migrations`. If you do not use migrations, consider using it. It's really useful when you change your model and want to preserve your date. By the way, I don't know if `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` still works with EF6.